# can two node scripts on the same machine block each other?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I have a parent node file (an express server) that spawns node children that run some computationally intense task, will the children block the parent?

Comment: It depends. If there's a single CPU core or child process heavily uses IO or other common resource, it will - as any other process.

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances this should not happen, a child process and its parent should not block each other. It's the operating system's job to prevent this.

However if you're running computationally intensive tasks, this may slow down the system entirely and prevent the operating system from doing its job.

There are also the situations where inter-process communication happens between the parent and child processes, and one of them waits for data from the other. However inter-process communication is a totally different topic.